# wordpress multisite custom css link wrong

Tags: css, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've installed Wordpress multisite on a local environment mac vhost apache and it works however, when I upload a theme it works fine on the main site. 
but if I activate the same theme on a subdirectory it works without the custom css wich appears as a 404 error it creates a link with a number added to the end of the url.

Has anyone ever had this problem? is this a theme issue or the settings on either the htaccess  or apache vhost?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: -1 for lack of basic literacy skills and failure to listen to the spell checker you were supplied with. Consider editing your question for clarity so people can decide if it's even on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Following the above reply by user @user6170930 and the voting down:

[Folks are rushing to pound new users down with "this belongs on meta!", "this is off topic", "this is a duplicate!" and "read the FAQ!". (Which is correct, but should be done nicer) All this, of course, is accompanied by a flurry of downvotes. This is not very welcoming to new users who don't know about meta, the FAQ, or what counts as off-topic.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)